# JS Timezone calculation goes over 24

Tags: javascript, time

I'm making a timezone calculator thing. To calculate time I use `getUTCHours` and add whatever the offset is. I have come into a problem where when its especially late, for AU timezones it'll go past 24. Is there anyway I can prevent this?

Comment: How can we help you if you don't show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var offset = 10;
var dt= new Date();
var hours = dt.getUTCHours() + offset;

// Wrap the hours around back to 24
var hourfixed = hours % 24;
var hourfixed2 = hours > 24 ? hours - 24 : hours;

console.log(hourfixed);
console.log(hourfixed2);
```